# How to use text input value with jquery get?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use the value from a text input when using jquery get?

It works with the value from a select input, but for some reason the value from the text input doesnt get sent to the next page (updateName.php)

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script>
        function updateName(){
         $.get('updateName.php', {name : $( "#name" ).val()});
        }
        function updateGender(){
         $.get('updateGender.php', {rego : $( "#gender" ).val()});
        }
</script>
</head>


<body>


<input type="text" id="name" onchange="updateName()" size="10%"> 

        <select id="gender" onchange="updateGender()">
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
    </select>


</body>
```

Comment: you need not to to bind onchange event with input, if you want to update the value once its completely written in the input field then bind function with blur event

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

The problem wasnt that the text wasnt being sent to the next page.

The problem was that on the next page I forgot to surround the value with apostrophes.

Like this:

```
$sql="UPDATE people SET name='$name' WHERE id=1";
```

The problem was it used to be like this:

```
    $sql="UPDATE people SET name=$name WHERE id=1";
```

Comment: you should consider using PHP's PDO class for sending data between your SQL database, because now you're vulnerable to SQL injection